# How to include Nvidia driver when installing Linux?

Tags: drivers, system-installation

Long story short, I'm trying to run Linux on my laptop and it's not quite working out. I've figured out the cause - Nvidia driver. How did I find out? Because Pop_OS with Nvidia driver is the only distro that works, not even Pop_OS without Nvidia driver (so nothing special with Pop_OS itself).

I think the solution is to either somehow include Nvidia driver with the installation - which I couldn't find an answer on the stack. I cannot install the driver after booting the system, because I cannot get past login (system freezes);

Or I can boot Linux with integrated GPU and install the driver after the system is up, but I don't know how to do this. I can get to grub menu with most distros.

Please help, and thank you in advance :)

Comment: You can boot into a live Linux distribution and choot into your current installation then install things.

Comment: I think the smart thing to do would be to force a `runlevel 3` versus a graphical `5` for the install, that would take graphics [nvidia] out of the equation entirely.  nvidia driver is a *kernel module*, I don't know how you could manage something like that at install time before the kernel itself is installed... normally there are install options to include or not include nouveau and other things, that's where you need to research to figure out how to get through the install process.

Comment: *Because Pop_OS with Nvidia driver is the only distro that works...*  I think there are many other distro's that will work on your laptop.

Comment: I have not had a problem booting then installing nvidia drivers in Mint, debian or Ubuntu. Find a tutorial online on installing nvidia drivers for the distro you want to use and do as ron suggested. I would recommend Mint or Ubuntu as there are lots of tutorials on how to install nvidia drivers.